# UILabels and Unicode

Tags: objective-c, ios, unicode, uilabel

I know questions similar to this have been asked, but I haven't found a satisfactory answer.

I'm trying to create a UILabel to display an equation. I don't like having multiple labels for exponents and subscripts, though, because I'm going to be making calculations, and the positions of the exponents and subscripts will have to shift to maintain formatting. Instead, I'd like to enter in the Unicode forms of superscript and subscript 'n' (0x207F and 0x2099 respectively) within my UILabel, and have them shift accordingly when the answers change. I've been searching for a while now, and I haven't been able to find an answer. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

you can assign a unicode in uilabel as follows -

```
[yourLabel settext:@"\u207F and \u2099"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%C` format specifier for unicode.

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"String with unicode %C", 0x207F];
```

Comment: When I run this, the program crashes. Here is my code:

solutionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
@" a%C  = %@ * %@%C - %@ * n *%@%C", 
0x2099,
[solutionSet objectAtIndex:1], 
[solutionSet objectAtIndex:0], 
0x207f,
[solutionSet objectAtIndex:2],
[solutionSet objectAtIndex:0],
0x207f];

Comment: What is the crash message? What are the contents of solutionsSet?

Comment: No error message comes up in the console. The application just crashes. solutionsSet is an array of NSNumbers.

Comment: If objects in solutionSet are NSNumbers then you can't use %@ as format specifier. %@ is for NSString. You need to convert your NSNumber to NSString. Try [[solutionsSet objectAtIndex:1] stringValue].

Comment: Tried it, still crashes unfortunately. Any other thoughts?