# Is there a way to use math symbol?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UILabels and Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839716/uilabels-and-unicode)

Is there a way to use math symbols in UILabels and UITextField just like the html ÷ × −, ° etc.?

Comment: Looks pretty similar to [this question][1]. In short, you want Unicode.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839716/uilabels-and-unicode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the HTML encodings, but you can embed the actual symbols directly into your code or your XIB files as Xcode treats Objective-C source files as Unicode / UTF-8.

To convert a string `myHTMLString` which has the encoded symbols, use

```
NSString* convertedString = [myHTMLString stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];
```

and use this NSString* category:   (Just include "NSString+HTML.m" in your source) https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m

Comment: The array that i pulled from server via NSURL has symbols formatted in html unicode. Is there a way to search the strings within the array for these unicodes and replacing them with the equivalent Unicode in mac/xcode?

Comment: Oh, well, in that case, `- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;`

Answer (score 2):

Just drag the symbols from Mac OS X' Character Viewer to Xcode. Than it should look like

```
label.text = @"÷ × −, ° ";
```

No need to deal with codes or html-entities.

If you have html-entities in your text, this category might be helpful: [GTMNSString+HTML](https://gist.github.com/takuma104/ntlniph/blob/master/gtm/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.h)

Comment: so how do i convert '&divide;'symbol pulled from within an array via NSURL?